# c# updating a progress form from external methods during a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Prepared for downvotes but I am really nowhere near getting to grips with the ins and outs of threading with this backgroundworker, but I've managed to just about get a structure for what I want:

```
public class cls1
    {

        private FormProgress myProgForm = new FormProgress();
        public BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();   // new instance of bkgworker

        public void prepare_a_job()
        {
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;                // Allows the worker to report progress
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;   // Adding handler to update progress
            worker.DoWork += job1;                              // Adding handler for the ACTUAL JOB METHOD

            myProgForm.Show();                                  // Show the prog update form
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();                            // Start the job, already! Wo lo loo
        }

        void job1(object sender, EventArgs e)                   // Do 0 to 100
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i); // ReportProgress uses percentages
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            // THIS IS WHERE I'D INSERT ANOTHER METHOD
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.ProgressPercentage == 100)  // If the % gets to 100
            {
                myProgForm.UPDATEME("", true);   // then pass true to close progressForm
            }
            else
            {
                myProgForm.UPDATEME("Counting\n" + e.ProgressPercentage);  // else just update 
            }

        }
    }
```

And on my `FormProgress` I just have this method:

```
public void UPDATEME(string MSG, bool finish = false)
    {
        this.label1.Text = MSG;
        this.Refresh();
        if (finish) { this.Close(); }
    }
```

Messy, right? But it works (and I've been trying to find/learn this stuff for 24 hours and this is the first thing I even remotely understand.

The issue I'm having with this mess, is calling the UPDATEME() method from any other methods I want to call during the `job1` routine - e.g. in reality this won't just be a loop to waste time, it'll be a set of conditions to call a tonne of other methods in various orders.

I tried bunging in a 2nd method into `job1` and within that 2nd method call `UPDATEME` but it's not a thread-safe cross-thread update...

I think it might have something to do with Invoking but then I also read something about MSDN BackgroundWorker was another way to allow thread-safe without invoke and then my head exploded and my brain fell out.

**How can I always refer to my `ProgressForm.UPDATEME("new progress message")` method within any other method in my code?**

**EDIT:**

For instance I'd insert a call to this 2nd method in the `job1` call

```
void myOtherMethod()
    {
        (worker).ReportProgress(0);
        myProgForm.UPDATEME("Doing part 1");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        myProgForm.UPDATEME("Doing part 2");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        myProgForm.UPDATEME("Doing part 3");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `event`s?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/  I think this is what you're asking for.

Comment: Why can't you just call `ReportProgress()` from your other methods within the `job1` method? It's no different from calling it within this loop. The `ProgressChanged` event handler will still send the updates to your UI. Maybe you can show us what you've tried so far to extend this current sample.

Comment: Well, yes and no, I'm fairly comfortable with having event handlers prescribed in good old Excel VBA and even adding a few handlers to events in c#/vb.Net but when it comes to calling events asynchronously I'm a total virgin and I'm learning by doing! Just not doing very well :D

Comment: I did try to call the line `(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);` in another method, and just used `worker` as the `sender` bit (after moving it to public property instead of within method) but it still says it's not cross-thread-safe

Comment: I edited to show a 2nd method that'd call the update event but I think the only way I can proceed right now is to always have that update called on the 1st level method (`Job1`). So any nested methods will have to execute fully, report back, then the 1st level will call an update. Not ideal and I still don't understand why a nested thread can't call the method if it's called linearly/synchronously but oh well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I always refer to my ProgressForm.UPDATEME("new progress
>   message") method within any other method in my code?

Like this:

```
public void UPDATEME(string MSG, bool finish = false)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.UPDATEME(MSG, finish)));
    }
    else
    {
        this.label1.Text = MSG;
        if (finish) { this.Close(); }
    }
}
```

> I don't really understand how invoking the method from within itself
>   gets round the fact the method is called outside the 1st level
>   thread ...

It is confusing at first as this is a recursive call.  The "meat" is that `Invoke()` runs whatever is inside it on the same thread that created the control (the form itself in this case).  When we enter the method the second time (due to recursion) the check returns false and we safely run the else block on the UI thread.

You can actually get rid of the check (and recursion) by always calling `Invoke()` whether it's needed or not like this:

```
public void UPDATEME(string MSG, bool finish = false)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.label1.Text = MSG;
        if (finish) { this.Close(); }
    }));
}
```

Here is an alternate version that still checks if `Invoke()` is required, but doesn't use recursion (less confusing, but we've now introduced duplicate code):

```
public void UPDATEME(string MSG, bool finish = false)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.label1.Text = MSG;
            if (finish) { this.Close(); }
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        this.label1.Text = MSG;
        if (finish) { this.Close(); }
    }
}
```

For those that are "detail oriented", here is an approach/variation (I'm using `MethodInvoker` instead of `Action`) showing one way to remove the duplicate code above:

```
public void UPDATEME(string MSG, bool finish = false)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.updater(MSG, finish);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.updater(MSG, finish);
    }
}

private void updater(string MSG, bool finish = false) // NOT thread safe, thus the private (don't call directly)
{
    this.label1.Text = MSG;
    if (finish) { this.Close(); }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I had read that bit on an MSDN page, I thought it was for other thread types excluding the BackgroundWorker, I'd even started typing similar (but would have got lost at the Lamda expression) - I don't really understand how invoking the method from within itself gets round the fact the method is called outside the 1st level thread but MASSIVE thanks for one-lining it for me. Tried it and it works!!!